# Apache dav-svn. Obvious security issue?

Tags: security, svn

While fiddling around with a custom look for the web interface for svn over http/Apache2 i encountered some simple enough configuration instructions:

**The [svn-book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.browsing) states:**

Chapter Repository Browsing subsection:

### Listing repositories

If you're serving a collection of repositories from a single URL via the SVNParentPath directive, then it's also possible to have
Apache display all available repositories to a web browser. Just activate the SVNListParentPath directive:

```
<Location /svn>
DAV svn
SVNParentPath /var/svn
SVNListParentPath on
...
</Location>
```

If a user now points her web browser to the URL http://host.example.com/svn/, she'll see a list of all Subversion re-
positories sitting in /var/svn. **Obviously, this can be a security problem, so this feature is turned off by default.**

*What is the Obvious security problem I am missing?*

Comment: Perhaps not all repositories should be visible by default? They're encouraging you to be explicit and only select for public visibility those that should be public rather than assuming everything should be visible and preconfiguring for that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly a critical security issue - more like a privacy issue.

It's referring to the fact that repositories can be private, and that listing them by path would publicise their existence. Think of it like directory listings in Apache - when enabled, if there's no index file, you'll get a list of files in that directory. This is a security problem because people might find innards of your system that you didn't want them to see.

Comment: I wish they'd be more explicit about this in the svn-book if this is their security objection. It is a bit too obvious in my taste.  "Your index will provide links to repositories", well duh =). The security practise of using non disclosed urls on public sites is of course akin to key under the doormat  security.

Comment: Agreed, though security through obscurity is valid in a few situations. It provides cheap protection from those who might accidently stumble across things, giving you time to build real security when you have the time.